# Make react native navigator go back to previous screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I have a tab navigator (with 3 screens) then each of these have also 2 or 3 screen each.

```
TabNavigator => "A,B,C"
A stack => "1,2,3"
```

Sometimes I'llgo from 1 to 2, and sometimes from B to 2 (for example), I want that when pressing the back button navigates to the previous screens so 1 for first example and B on the seconds. But right now only goes to 1.
Here is my navigation stack:

```
const RaidsStack = createStackNavigator({
  Raids: { screen: RaidsScreen, }, 
  CreateRaid: { screen: CreateRaidScreen, }, 
  
})
const ChatsStack = createStackNavigator({
  Chats: { screen: ChatsScreen }, 
  ChatRoom: { screen: ChatRoomScreen, }, 
})
const SettingsStack = createStackNavigator({
  Settings: { screen: SettingsScreen },
  EditProfile: { screen: editProfileScreen }, 
  Start: { screen: StartScreen }, 
  
})
const StartStack = createStackNavigator({
  Tabs: { screen: SettingsScreen },
  Register: { screen: editProfileScreen }, 
  Start: { screen: StartScreen }, 
  
})
const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Raids: { screen: RaidsStack },
    Chats: { screen: ChatsStack },
    Settings: { screen: SettingsStack }
  },
  
  {
    tabBarPosition: "bottom",
    tabBarComponent: props => {

      return (
        <Footer>
          <FooterTab>
            <Button
              vertical
              active={props.navigation.state.index === 0}
              onPress={() => props.navigation.replace('Tabs', {}, NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'RaidsStack' }))}>
              <Icon name="egg" />
              <Text>Raids</Text>
            </Button>
            <Button
              vertical
              active={props.navigation.state.index === 1}
              onPress={() => props.navigation.replace('Tabs', {}, NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Chats' }))}>
              <Icon name="mail" />
              <Text>Chats</Text>
            </Button>
            <Button
               vertical
              active={props.navigation.state.index === 2}
              onPress={() => props.navigation.replace('Tabs', {}, NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Settings' }))}>
              <Icon name="settings" />
              <Text>Settings</Text>
            </Button>
          </FooterTab>
        </Footer>
      );
    }
  }
)

const AppStack = createStackNavigator({
  Start: { screen: StartScreen },
  Register: { screen: RegisterScreen },
  Tabs: TabNavigator,
  Raids: { screen: RaidsScreen },
  Chats: { screen: ChatsScreen },
  Settings: { screen: SettingsScreen }
}, {
  headerMode: 'none',
})
```

How to do it? I'm new to react and react navigation.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest looking at the documentation https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/
Since you also using nested navigator I suggest looking at this page too https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/
It’s exactly tells shows you the example of nested navigator with a tab

Hope this material will help you!

Comment: is there any easier navigator to use?

Comment: The documentaition that I've given you is the easiest navigator to use. I reccomend take a look at this docentantion before switching the libraries. This navigator has examples on how to use nested navigators (which is what you are trying to do in your code) and function on how to go back.

Comment: On the other hand this library is also uses stack library like you do.